# Clonezilla and software RAID array theory

Tags: backup, raid, software-raid

I don't have enough hardware to try this out myself, but since Clonezilla doesn't support backing up software RAIDs, I've been trying to think of ways to backup my RAID0.  Since all of the information for a software RAID is stored on the disks themselves, would it not be possible to use `dd` to do a direct clone of all the disks in the array to make a backup of the array itself?  Even if Clonezilla would refuse to backup the disks, could I not use `dd` to manually backup the entire disk array to individual files and then restore them to a new location if needed/wanted?

Comment: Theoretically yes, that should work if you do everything exactly the right way.  But I haven't tested, so I am not making this an answer.  You should go setup a VM and test.

Comment: Oooo, great idea.  I was working with VMs earlier and somehow managed to not even thinking about testing with one of them.  Thanks.